# web server / iis won't install on server 2012

Tags: iis, web-server, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to install Web server role / iis to my dynamic Windows 2012 cloud server but keep getting the following errors:

If I have the following not installed and try to install web server / iis 8.0 it keeps telling me I have a restart pending. If I go to tools I can see iis manager and open it and navigate to local host however the role is not added to the server and on restarting it all disappears.

- “Windows Process Activation Services"

If I install the above and try and install I get the following error code which google has not revealed much

- 0x800f0922

I have so far tried the following
- deleting the main folder on drive C:
- tried installing via powershell and command promt
- removing iis by running the following command "start /w pkgmgr.exe /uu:IIS-WebServerRole;WAS-WindowsActivationService" 
- I have also run the following command: dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
- I have cleared / deleted the updates to see if something was in corrupted.
- I have also ran the .NET fix application.

Other roles still install on the system.

Has anyone got any ideas what else can try before I have to wipe the system which seems a bit over kill and a lot of work as this is a live production server.

Thanks in advance.
J

Answer (score 0):

Check the IIS and CBS (component based setup) logs, should yield more details on what failed. 
IIS Logs: c:\windows\iisx.log (where 'x' is the version of IIS you're installing)
CBS Logs: c:\windows\logs\cbs

Comment: Thanks for this in the iis log I get the following errors                                    : < WARNING! > Failed to detect if config redirection is enabled. result=0x80070032.Assuming config is not redirected and continuing and Ignoring acceptable LaunchCommand failure 0x80070002

Comment: Anything in the CBS logs? Searching for the LaunchCommand error suggests executing the pkgmgr command you've already tried.

Comment: I found this towards the end but not sure what to look for? 2016-05-04 17:21:21, Info                  CSI    00000124 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:520{260},l:38{19}]"\??\C:\inetpub\logs" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft-Windows-

Comment: Another part of the log the code its too long to upload as a comment: Startup: Retrying failed packages.
2016-05-04 17:22:11, Info                  CBS    Startup: Processing complete. [HRESULT = 0x80004005 - E_FAIL

Comment: Start by deleting c:\inetpub (subdirectories and all). Then dump the c:\windows\iisx.log. Trying to get to a clean slate.  
The go with:  
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth  
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth  
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth  

Reboot and attempt to reinstall IIS. If that doesn't work, consider lobotomizing the box and starting over.

Comment: Ok doing it now, should I restart the server after running all the dism or try installing without restarting? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Restart to be safe

Comment: Tried all the above, no corruptions where found but when tried to install the web server role it just says a failed due to a the server requiring a restart. IIS is available in the tools section until I reboot. Thanks for your help looks like I have to move the whole system to a new server backups also have the same issue.

Comment: Ok so if I install the WPAS I get the error 0x800f0922 which in the iis log shows this: [05/05/2016 04:25:44] [ ***** IIS 8.0 Component Based Setup ***** ]
[05/05/2016 04:25:44] "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iissetup.exe" /install CoreWebEngine
[05/05/2016 04:25:44] < !!FAIL!! > SETUP_COMMON_UTIL::IsDomainController result=0x80070005
[05/05/2016 04:25:44] < !!FAIL!! > Install of component CoreWebEngine result=0x80070005
[05/05/2016 04:25:44] < !!FAIL!! > COMPONENT::ExecuteCommand result=0x80070005

Comment: Is the server in question a domain controller?

Comment: No its not but it might have been one in the past. Sorry I inherited the server but I think it was at some point. Does that make a difference?

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: @user5389726598465 never resolved it. Spun up a secondary box to handle WSUS.

Comment: @SloanOzanne sigh, that's what I did too reverting to a 2 month old snapshot. Don't have time to test individually if it was one of the KB updates or what.